# How to define the order of reducers execution in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Assume I have action `A` which is dispatched to reducer `R1` and `R2`. I also have smart component `C` which is `connect`ed to the states returned by `R1` and `R2`

Is it possible that component `C` were rerendered when `R1` is executed but before `R2` is executed?

How if I want to rerender `C` only when both `R1` and `R2` are executed? Or is it possible to tell Redux `dispatcher` to dispatch the action to `R2` first?

*`R1` is actually the `results` state returned by redux `normalizr` and `R2` is the `entities` state. The `entities` are needed to denormalize the `results`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Is it possible that component C were rerendered when R1 is executed but before R2 is executed?

No, it is not possible if you use a single store like Redux docs suggest.

In Redux, you combine reducers with `combineReducers()`. This means that from Redux’s point of view, **there is only a single reducer, and it is synchronous**. Sure, it calls your two reducers, but the Redux store only begins notifying subscribers after it gets the new state value from its root reducer, so it is guaranteed that **all your reducers have already been executed by the time the views are notified**.

Comment: I had a situation similar to this where a selector was being called and causing an error because a value was undefined. That value was based on a single action being handled by 2 reducers. The select was being referenced in the mapStateToProps function of a container. Any insight into this Dan?

Answer (score 1):

Redux actions are dispatched synchronously, so all side effects of an action will occur immediately after the action is dispatched. This means your component will only re-render once since React doesn't re-render immediately on state change (it seems to instead defer until the next event loop or animation frame) even if you call `setState` multiple times.

You can define the order of dispatch by simply changing the order you're calling `store.dispatch`. Call `R1.dispatch` first if you want all side effects of `R1` changing to happen first.

Comment: The thing is, both R1 and R2 subscribe to the same action A. So I can't separate the dispatch