# How to save response to localStore with Redux Thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

1. They propose to use `subscribe` for vanilla Redux here:

[Where to write to localStorage in a Redux app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305661/where-to-write-to-localstorage-in-a-redux-app)

2. Here for Redux Toolkit he propose to sort out local storage write operation in a separate thunk, and make dispatch from one reducer to the thunk.

[How to subscribe to state outside React component in Redux Toolkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69053186/how-to-subscribe-to-state-outside-react-component-in-redux-toolkit)

What do you think?

Right now I have this simple solution, one reducer, it saves to state and to localStore also, I do not face any issue yet. Shall I change?

```js
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(me.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
                state.authnRes = payload
                localStorage.setItem('authnRes', JSON.stringify(payload))
            })
```

Shall I make a separate thunk, and move the `localStorage.setItem('authnRes', JSON.stringify(payload))` into there?

He says:

> Reducer is never an appropriate place to do this because reducers should be pure and have no side effects.

---

Do you see any drawback in this approach? Thunk fires an other thunk with local store operation.

```
export const loginEmail = createAsyncThunk(
    `${namespace}/loginEmail`,
    async (req: any, { dispatch }) => {
        const { data } = await axios(req).then((res) => {
            dispatch(persistAuthnUser(res.data)) // <--- here
            return res
        })
        return data
    }
)
```

and here `persist` happens:

```js
export const persistAuthnUser = createAsyncThunk(
    `${namespace}/persistAuthnUser`,
    async (data: any, { dispatch }) => {
        return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
            localStorage.setItem('authnRes', JSON.stringify(data))
        })
    }
)
```

Comment: Personally, I recently moved my persist-session logic from `subscribe` to my session reducer slice due to some problems (for example, needed to remove the storage manually on logout). Got a cleaner solution moving all the logic to the slice, now all persist-session logic is centralized. Working perfectly in all cases I tested.

Comment: Would you show an exaple how you did it? Did you create an other thunk, and reducer dispatch that thunk?

Comment: @Rashomon You're still removing from localStorage manually on logout in your snippet below.

Comment: But now its centralized in a single place, the session reducer. Previously I had to remove persist-session storage on every `dispatch(logoutAction)` across the application.

Comment: This still holds true: "Reducer is never an appropriate place to do this because reducers should be pure and have no side effects." Why not do it in a middleware? it has access to all dispatched actions and you can call `store.getState()`. Writing to localStorage *sometimes* in *some* reducers is not great for separation of concerns.

Comment: Yeah a middleware sound good. Honestly dont have created a redux middleware before (just using orhers). I will have a look. I think my solution is clean, but  its true doesnt accomplish not having side effects.

Comment: @Rashomon, I do not get it why your solution is better than my, you call a method from resolver, but resolver is still 'overloaded', resolver can not return before `removePersistedSession` or `savePersistedSession` finished. Why don't you put local store operation in a thunk?

Comment: Added a new solution using a middleware instead of a reducer to avoid side effects.

Comment: I think it is way too complex how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work implementing a middleware:

```
import {
  isAsyncThunkAction,
  isPending,
  isRejected,
  isFulfilled,
  isAnyOf,
  createListenerMiddleware,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'


const sessionListenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware()

sessionListenerMiddleware.startListening({
  matcher: isAnyOf(isAsyncThunkAction(me)), // execute middleware every time "me" is dispatched
  effect: (action, listenerApi) => {
    // listenerApi.getState() // You can also access state using this function

    const shouldSaveSession = isFulfilled(me) // save session every time async thunk "me" is fulfilled

    if (shouldSaveSession(action)) {
      // Middleware is executed after reducer, so we can assume state is already updated
      localStorage.setItem('authnRes', JSON.stringify(action.payload))
    }
  },
})

export const sessionMiddleware = sessionListenerMiddleware.middleware
```

Dont forget to add the middleware to your store:

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware()
      .concat(otherMiddlewareYouMightHave)
      .concat(sessionMiddleware), // concat it here
})
```